# Making drop down menu by click using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an simple example of drop down menu by click using AJAX:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry313/1s62x8hc/2/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropmenu">Dropdown menu</a>
<ul style="display:none">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var click = function () {
            var divObj = $(this).next();
            var nstyle = divObj.css("display");
            if (nstyle == "none") {
                divObj.slideDown(false, function () {
                    $("html").bind("click", function () {
                        divObj.slideUp();
                    });
                });
            }
        };
        $(".dropmenu").click(click);
    });
```

Is it possible to make the same without any script, just using CSS?

**EDIT:** Updated link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can trigger a css click using a hack!!**

Work with an checkbox!!

Sample:

```css
      ul{
            display: none;
        }
        #checkbox{
            opacity: 0;
        }
        #checkbox:checked + ul {
            
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <label for="checkbox">Dropdown menu</label>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

You can use transitions to animate the show an hide effect :)
This is just a very simple example!!

Mention: this is a CSS3 hack if you need borwser support for old browsers this is not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Very good example!

Answer (score 0):

No, You need a least three line of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't have an onClick method or something similar in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

pure Html/CSS Solution using html nested lists - would still need a few lines of JS to make it onClick

http://jsfiddle.net/t1zw41ep/2/

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Menu</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

See: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: I need the drop after mouse click

Comment: The code snippet by user Steven Wave using the checkbox hack is the only way to do it without JS or JQuery, however using CSS3 is limited in that it will only run onmouseclick in modern browsers.